# Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent and Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, wear-os

I'm making an image slider for Wear OS and have a screen with a ViewPager and two buttons:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/sViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:onClick="btnNextClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/prev"
            android:onClick="btnPrevClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

With the following code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : WearableActivity() {

    private lateinit var btnNext: Button
    private lateinit var btnPrev: Button
    private lateinit var sViewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var dotsLayout: LinearLayout
    private var dots: Array<TextView?> = arrayOfNulls(5)

    private lateinit var sliderAdapter: SliderAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // find view id
        initView()

        sliderAdapter = SliderAdapter(this)

        sViewPager.adapter = sliderAdapter

        sViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener)

        addBottomDots(0)
    }

    //Moves to next ViewPAge
    fun btnNextClick(v : View) {
        val current = getItem(1)
        if (current < sliderAdapter.image_slide.size) {
            sViewPager.currentItem = current
        }
    }

    //Moves to previous ViewPage
    fun btnPrevClick(v : View) {
        val current = getItem(-1)
        if (current > 0) {
            sViewPager.currentItem = current
        }
    }

    //Get next/precious item position
    private fun getItem(i: Int): Int {
        return sViewPager.currentItem + i
    }

    //Initialize views in variable
    private fun initView() {
        sViewPager = findViewById(R.id.sViewPager)
        dotsLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutDots)
        btnPrev = findViewById(R.id.btn_prev)
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next)
    }

    //OnPageChangeListener to change Dots  depending on position
    private val onPageChangeListener = object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            addBottomDots(position)
        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(arg0: Int, arg1: Float, arg2: Int) {}

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(arg0: Int) {}
    }

    //Create Dots array and depending on position will be variable
    private fun addBottomDots(currentPage: Int) {
        dotsLayout.removeAllViews()
        for (i in dots.indices) {
            dots[i] = TextView(this)
            dots[i]!!.text = Html.fromHtml("&#8226;")
            dots[i]!!.textSize = 35f
            dots[i]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colortWhite))
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i])
        }
        if (dots.isNotEmpty()) 
            dots[currentPage]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
    }
}
```

In MainActivity we create an instance of SliderAdapter (class with inheritance of PagerAdapter) and assign it to ViewPager.adapter:

**SliderAdapter.kt**

```
class SliderAdapter(private var context: Context)  :  PagerAdapter() {

    private lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater

    //Hardcoded Image Array
    var image_slide = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.aiv_robot_image,
        R.drawable.aiv_robot_image,
        R.drawable.aiv_robot_image
    )

    //HardcodedHeaderArray
    var heading_slide = arrayOf(
        "Robot1",
        "Robot2",
        "Robot3"
    )

    //Get size of heading_slide
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heading_slide.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, Object: Any): Boolean {
        return view == Object
    }

    //Override instantiateItem to create view using slide_layout and filling it whit previous declared arrays
    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false)
        container.addView(view)

        val slide_imageView : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val slideHeading : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

        slide_imageView.setImageResource(image_slide[position])
        slideHeading.text = heading_slide[position]

        return view
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, Object: Any) {
        container.removeView(Object as RelativeLayout?)
    }
}
```

Layout:
**slide_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aiv_robot_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now here comes my problem, when I try to move anyhting or try to use buttons I get these warnings:

**Warning 1**

> W/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus:
>   MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0,
>   x[0]=191.99219, y[0]=277.98828, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER,
>   buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1,
>   historySize=0, eventTime=29492702, downTime=29492702, deviceId=0,
>   source=0x1002 }

**Warning 2**

> W/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus:
>   MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0,
>   x[0]=191.99219, y[0]=277.98828, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER,
>   buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1,
>   historySize=0, eventTime=29492805, downTime=29492702, deviceId=0,
>   source=0x1002 }

And doesn't do anything more. I have found some threads with the same warning but some of them are for keyboard problems or say that there is a finish() function, which is not the same as mine.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What happens if you simplify? For instance, remove the buttons and indicator dots... does the ViewPager itself work with horizontal swipe?

Comment: If i remove buttons and indicator dots (both) it works, with any of both it still says this warning.